# How to get translate message in controller Laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have file **excel.php** by the path `/resources/lang/en/excel.php`

Then in controller I tried to fetch word by key:

```
use Lang;

echo Lang::get('excel.idEvent');
```

Also I  tried:

```
dd(echo __('excel.idEvent'));
```

Whats is right way to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use JSON translation files, you might have to use `__()`.

Here are all the ways to use:

```
@lang('...')  // only in blade files
__('...')
Lang::get('...')
trans('...')
app('translator')->get('...')
Lang::trans('...')
```

They all defer to `\Illuminate\Translation\Translator::get()` eventually.

Comment: I use array instead json

Comment: Then everything except `__()`. I usually use the helper function `trans()`.

Comment: That's if you use the Facade, yes. But I suggest the helper function. That's the most convenient one. `trans('excel.idEvent');` And you won't forget an import, as you don't need one :)

Comment: No result: `dd(trans('excel.idVisitor'));`

Comment: Can you please show the content of your `excel.php` file? The path as it is written above it is correct btw.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/192985/discussion-between-nakov-and-opv).

Answer (score 4):

First, your excel.php file must be in the right format:

```
<?php 
    return [
        'welcome' => 'Welcome to our application'
    ];
```

The right way to get it on your blade template in fact it is:

```
echo __('excel.welcome');
```

or

```
echo __('Welcome to our application');
```

The way to do it on your controller is:

```
use Lang;

Lang::get('excel.welcome');
```

If you are not using Facades: use \Illuminate\Support\Facades\Lang;

You can also use the trans() function, ex:

```
Route::get('/', function () {

    echo trans('messages.welcome');

});
```

Comment: the excel.php file should be there where you put it. Within resouces/lang/en/* where "en" is your locale. Have you defined de default locale and fallback locale on the config/app.php?